# Bootstrap 4 class available to increase the thickness of <hr /> tag without CSS

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I don't want to use custom CSS to achieve this. Is there any bootstrap 4 class that can be used to adjust the thickness / color of the `<hr />` tag?

Comment: class : bg-dark || for thickness add custom boder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `bg-dark` class. The reason why this works is because to add a "thickness" to an hr, you need to give him any background color. And this bootstrap 4 class does just that.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<hr/>

<hr class="text-dark bg-dark"/>
```

`text-dark` is for older browsers, and `bg-dark` for modern ones.

https://jsfiddle.net/y9u0kfnr/